# Array packing and unpacking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, database, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google maps api, I want to pack google marker information such as lat-lon, infowindow(address of the location) into an array. Later I want to unpack the array in a different function so as to push the collected information into database. I'm able to pack lat-lon info as they are automatically available. But for address (info window) I have to create a property in the marker and then store it in a container. I'm unable to store it in a container. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: @Abhinav: I have tried using a string which holds a container - div id . But I don't know the format of storing address in it. And the string is a property of my marker.

Comment: show us your code , that will serve us an entry point to solve your problem. this is how SO works.

Comment: @Abhinav : my code is similar to the answer given by Corey Hoffman, read the comments in answer for what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your question complete.  Put what your code looks like (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue) and what you have tried in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

1. Create an associative array somewhere globally: `markers = {};`
2. Append the necessary information to the marker object when its created:

   ```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: latlng,
    });

    // The following block adds unique information to the marker object
    // Used to identify individual markers
    marker.id = marker_id; //Some unique id might be useful to store in the marker
    marker.infowindow = infowindow;
    marker.address = "Some Address";
   ```
3. Add the created marker object to the associative array using a unique identifier: `markers[marker_id] = marker;`

Following the above pattern should allow you to create an array of referencable and manageable marker objects.

Comment: I have written a similar code. But the address is dynamic i.e the marker takes up new address every time it is dragged. Also, I have N markers depending upon the situation, how to pack information of every incoming marker ?

Comment: If you put that code inside of wherever the markers are generated it will add all N markers to the array identified by some unique ID that you create. As for changing the address dynamically you can add the following event handler to the marker:                        `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() { markers[marker.id].address = "new address"; // or markers[marker.id].infowindow = new infowindow }`

Comment: I have written exactly similar code - the new address is dynamically generated with every new position i.e the array should automatically pickup the address after completing dragend event, for every new marker.